# Do I have to enable Remote Desktop Services to use Remote Web Workplace connect to computer

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services, windows-sbs-2011

We have an existing SBS 2011 Standard installation and I am trying to configure Remote Web Workplace.  So far I am able to connect to the Remote Web Access and use shared folders and connect to Outlook no problem.

The issue is configuring the "Connect to computer" feature.  When I click "Connect" for any of the computers I have configured to show up, I am prompted with the Remote Desktop Connection dialog. I select "Connect" there, and am prompted for credentials, which I enter.  After a moment I get an error saying "Remote Desktop Gateway server is temporarily unavailable".

After reading multiple forums I am now confused as to whether I need to upgrade to the premium add-on and configure Remote Desktop Services (formerly TS) or if there is just some other aspect of the configuration that I have not setup properly.  I have enabled the Remote Desktop Gateway role on the server, but that has not seemed to fix the issue.  Does RDS have to be enabled for the Remote Desktop Gateway to work correctly?

**TL;DR**

Do I need to enable Remote Desktop Services for the Remote Web Workplace connect to computer feature to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have SBS2011 hands-on experience, but for SBS2008, "Connect to a Computer" launches an active X control that connects to the standard remote desktop on the computer being connected to, passed through the Terminal Services Gateway.  [This appears to be the same way it works in 2011.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/remote-desktop-services-activex-1.aspx)

There's actually a service running on your SBS server called Remote Desktop Gateway.  [Make sure that it's running.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg680313.aspx) There is also a web site associated with the Remote Desktop Gateway which may need to be restarted.

Comment: Maybe I was looking in the wrong places but you are the first person who has finally given me an answer that lets me know Remote Desktop Connection is *NOT* the way this should be working.  I checked my active X settings on the client per the article you linked to & they look ok.  I have also confirmed that Remote Desktop Gateway service is running.  I inherited this & am thinking something must be mis-configured on the site.  +1 just for the Active X information though...reduces my troubleshooting surface area.

Comment: Yeah, Remote Desktop on SBS is not involved.  It's all IE/Active X on user's home machine (that does involve the remote desktop client, but invoked by Active X) -> SBS's IIS/Active X control/related service -> Remote desktop on the user's work machine.

Comment: P.S.  On SBS08 there is a separate IIS web site called "SBS Client Deployment Application."  Make sure it and its application pool are running.

Comment: While I'm still having issues with "Connect to a Computer" working, your answer & comments have solved the question I asked & given me more direction. Thanks for all your help!